# Connect EC2 to Git by ssh

Tags: amazon-web-services, github, amazon-ec2, ssh-keys

Having a EC2 instance with a Git repository, I need to update it by `ssh-key`.

I tried:

1. Add `authorized_keys` into GitHub. --> Not working and not the right way.
2. Create a new ssh-key, add it into EC2 console pair-key and add into GitHub. As ssh-add not working at EC2 instance, @Biswajit Mohanty suggested me to run ssh -T git@github.com, and got the proper answer but still getting 'permission denied (publickey). fatal: could not read from remote repository' when pulling.

I already configured the .git/config as it should:

```
    sshCommand = "ssh -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub"
```

[remote "origin"]
url = ssh://git@github.com/ArantecEnginheria/smartyplanet.git

Any suggestion about to success doing a 'pull' and update the code into that server?

Comment: Please add more detail about the steps you took and the errors you see. Is the key pair you generated via the AWS console assigned to your EC2 instance? Is the public key from that key pair in the Github authorized_keys? How are you executing git pull on the EC2 instance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You generally do not add an `authorized_keys` to GitHub. You [register a public SSH key](https://docs.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/adding-a-new-ssh-key-to-your-github-account) to your [GitHub user profile](https://github.com/settings/ssh/), in order to establish the proper authentication.

If you need to push to a GitHub  repository from an EC2 instance, (meaning from an [EC2 instance session](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-instance-lifecycle.html)), then said session should include a `~/.ssh/id_rsa` and  `~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub`: private/public key pair, with the public one registered to GitHub as mentioned above.

Comment: @NorthmaN Mohanty just repeated what I mentioned in my answer, which is based on default id_rsa keys, meaning no `~/.ssh/config` necessary (on the EC2 instance).

Comment: Yeah man! Both of you said what should be done... The theory is clear, but in practice it is not... I did the same in my own computer, and worked... (ssh-add the ssh-key too, but in EC2 not working...) I'm a developer, and that kind of stuff is quite far from me, I just need to push/pull code, not dealing with ssh keys, IP's... Thank you so much for your time.

Comment: @NorthmaN So did you try with default key, and without any ssh config?

Comment: Man!! You are the warlock!! It works!! Not need to define the sshCommand, just changing the protocol (https to ssh) in the config file url parameter! Thank you!

Answer (score 7):

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa 
Generating public/private rsa key pair.
Enter file in which to save the key (/c/Users/.ssh/id_rsa): ./yourgitkey
Enter passphrase (empty for no passphrase):  
Enter same passphrase again: 
Your identification has been saved in ./yourgitkey
Your public key has been saved in ./yourgitkey.pub
```

copy the content of the ./yourgitkey.pub to GitHub https://github.com/settings/keys

Add New SSH key and enter the ./yourgitkey.pub

To avoid Permission error :
make your private key permission to

```
chmod 400 ./yourgitkey
```

Enter the following:

```
$ ssh -T git@github.com
```

You may see a warning like this:

```
> The authenticity of host 'github.com (IP ADDRESS)' can't be established.
> RSA key fingerprint is SHA256:nThbg6kXUpJWGl7E1IGOCspRomTxdCARLviKw6E5SY8.
> Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)?
Verify that the fingerprint in the message you see matches GitHub's RSA public key fingerprint.
```

If it does, then type yes:

> Hi username! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not
> provide shell access.

You Are Ready Now !!!

Comment: Hi @Biswajit Mohanty ! I didn't 'ssh -T git@github.com'... I just did it and I got the right answer '...You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access....'. But pulling the code still saying 'permission denied (publickey). fatal: could not read from remote repository' . Repository .git/config file has defined 'sshCommand = "ssh -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub"' . Keep digging in IT stuff!

Comment: 'ssh -T git@github.com'...  is just to see if connections are working for GitHub with default keys, it is optional :D 

As you said you already got access without providing any key mentioned in ssh -T git@github.com.
So the SSH command was not needed,
'sshcommand' should contain the private key and I can see the public key is mentioned there in your question 

Anyway, you already got an answer. Cheers mate !!!

Comment: One thing to note, after setting this config on EC2 for example make sure to use SSH version of the clone URL!